# Retrieve custom properties with Neo4j/Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'd like to be able to retrieve some custom properties in my java 'node' from neo4j.
I would like if possible to use the latest version of spring boot/neo4j.

I would need to have both the name of the custom properties and the value.

From my research I think I've found something that is capable of doing what I want but I can't make it works.
Using SDN 6 it is possible to tag a collections with '@DynamicLabels'. But no matter how I try to query the database, the collections is always empty.

My node/entity:

```
@Node("asset")
public class Asset {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String owner;

    @DynamicLabels
    private List<String> properties = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

My repository:

```
@Repository
public interface AssetRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Asset, Long> {

    @Query("MATCH (pa: primary_assets) WHERE id(pa) = 14 RETURN pa")
    Asset test ();
}
```

I don't know if I'm heading the right way or if I totaly missed something.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the closest solution you have in Spring Data Neo4j would be to rely on [composite properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#custom.conversions.composite-properties).